# SQL Server BEFORE UPDATE trigger which adds in a timestamp on a field before UPDATE execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi good people of stackoverflow,

I am working on a trigger for a table on SQL SERVER 2008 R2 for auditing purpose which should add in a timestamp for the UPDATE_TS field before the UPDATE query is sent for execution. The result being that the update occurs with the original values to update on query plus the additional value of the UPDATE_TS as set by the trigger.

I have as well edited this question since I hear that inner-joins are not very heavy in terms of performance on triggers in comparison to not using them. I am not sure if this will add an additional overhead on the trigger as opposed to avoiding inner join in the trigger.

The example I am working on is below. Thank you for any help and suggestions!

Example Table is called MY_TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE [myschema].[MY_TABLE](
[MY_TABLE_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FIELD_TO_UPDATE] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[CREATE_TS] [datetime] NULL,
[UPDATE_TS] [datetime] NULL),
PRIMARY KEY (MY_TABLE_ID))
```

TRIGGER to create:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [myschema].[my_table_update_ts_trigger] ON [mydb].[myschema].[MY_TABLE]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE INTO MY_TABLE ([FIELD_TO_UPDATE],[UPDATE_TS])
    SELECT ins.FIELD_TO_UPDATE, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED as ins
END
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to identify the row(s) you need to update, and you do this with a join or semi-join. It's not going to get much more efficient than this, unless you simply don't perform the update at all:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [myschema].[my_table_update_ts_trigger] 
ON [myschema].[MY_TABLE]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET 
      FIELD_TO_UPDATE = i.FIELD_TO_UPDATE,
      UPDATE_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM myschema.MY_TABLE AS t
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON t.MY_TABLE_ID = i.MY_TABLE_ID;
END
GO
```

Here is the execution plan:

[image: Execution plan for instead of UPDATE trigger using INNER JOIN]

Since you need to match the rows in `inserted` to your base table, and since there may be more than one row that gets updated by any operation (triggers fire *per statement* in SQL Server, not *per row* like in some other platforms), and since this isn't a BEFORE update but an INSTEAD OF update (meaning you still have to actually perform the UPDATE that would have happened without the trigger in place), you need to have output from both tables in order to perform the update accurately. This means you need a JOIN, and you cannot use a SEMI-JOIN (e.g. EXISTS), which probably still violates your outlandish requirements anyway. If you only needed to update the timestamp, you could do this:

```
UPDATE t SET UPDATE_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  FROM myschema.MY_TABLE AS t
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE MY_TABLE_ID = t.MY_TABLE_ID);
```

Unfortunately, that will not work, because `FIELD_TO_UPDATE` gets lost without actually pulling in the `inserted` pseudo-table in a proper join.

Another way is to use a CROSS APPLY, e.g.:

```
 UPDATE t SET 
   FIELD_TO_UPDATE = i.FIELD_TO_UPDATE,
   UPDATE_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM  inserted AS i
CROSS APPLY myschema.MY_TABLE AS t
WHERE i.MY_TABLE_ID = t.MY_TABLE_ID;
```

It, too, is missing the nasty JOIN keyword, but it is still performing a JOIN. You can see this because the execution plans are identical:

[image: Execution plan for instead of UPDATE trigger using CROSS APPLY]

Now, you can theoretically do this without a join, but that doesn't mean it will perform better. In fact I guarantee you beyond a shadow of a doubt that this will be less efficient, even though it does not contain a single four-letter word like JOIN:

```
    DECLARE @NOW             DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            @MY_TABLE_ID     INT,
            @FIELD_TO_UPDATE VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
      SELECT MY_TABLE_ID, FIELD_TO_UPDATE FROM inserted;

    OPEN c;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @FIELD_TO_UPDATE, @MY_TABLE_ID;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      UPDATE myschema.MY_TABLE SET 
          FIELD_TO_UPDATE = @FIELD_TO_UPDATE,
                UPDATE_TS = @NOW
        WHERE MY_TABLE_ID = @MY_TABLE_ID;

      FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @FIELD_TO_UPDATE, @MY_TABLE_ID;
    END

    CLOSE c;
    DEALLOCATE c;
```

That said, if you think even for a second that this solution is going to be faster than the one with joins, I have some swampland in Florida to sell you. There are multiple bridges on the property, too. I'm not even going to bother showing the execution plans for this one.

Let's also compare what happens in an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger. Here is an example, probably similar to what you had:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myschema.ins_my_table
ON myschema.MY_TABLE
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  INSERT myschema.MY_TABLE(FIELD_TO_UPDATE, CREATE_TS)
    SELECT FIELD_TO_UPDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM inserted;
GO
```

This, too, will produce a plan that looks like two queries were executed:

[image: Execution plan for instead of INSERT trigger with no JOIN]

It is important to note that an INSTEAD OF trigger cancels the original update, and you are responsible for issuing your own (even though the plan still shows two queries).

One final option would be to use an AFTER trigger instead of an INSTEAD OF trigger. This will allow you to update the timestamp without the JOIN, because the FIELD_TO_UPDATE has already been updated. But in this case you really will see two queries, and two queries will really be executed (it won't just look that way in the plans).

**Some general comments**

> Since i'm going for performance increase I do not want to use any inner joins in the code used for the trigger.

This doesn't really make much sense; why do you think joins are bad for performance? Sounds like you've watched too many NoSQL videos. Please don't discard technology because you've heard it was bad or because you had a slow join once. Create the query that makes sense, optimize when it doesn't perform well, and come for help when you can't optimize. In almost all cases (there are exceptions, of course), the problem is indexing or statistics and not the fact that you used a JOIN keyword. That doesn't mean you should avoid all joins in all queries at all costs.

Comment: No inner joins please, that is my requirement. You have not answered the question.

Comment: @aruuuuu No disrespect, but do you know what an `INNER JOIN` is?

Comment: As well, I am not against joins, I am against putting a join in when I don't need to, because on a high performance db if I am doing 2 additional queries for each single query that is a 2 times slower. Does that help you understand what I am asking for?

Comment: @aruuuuu why is that a requirement? If you have a requirement to do no joining in SQL that is the worst requirement of all time.

Comment: if you know oracle, you will understand that I am looking for the equivalent of a before update.

Comment: ok can we please stop the flaming lol. I have a lot of joins in my code, but I do not want a join in the trigger.

Comment: and I did not hear anything bad about joins you are making a broad assumption. Why don't you ask me first what I think of joins ;)

Comment: @aruuuuu I don't really care what you think of joins or why you don't want them here. The requirement doesn't make sense, period. This is like going to Hertz and saying I want to drive to Tulsa but you better not give me any cars with *rubber* in their tires.

Comment: ok. I will keep what you said in mind, but looking at the traces on the profiler I do see an overhead on doing additional joins on every single update when I don't need to. I do use joins when I feel that I need to and I am all for them, but not in this isstance. But I will keep what you said in mind.

Comment: @aruuuuu You say *As well, I am not against joins, I am against putting a join in when I don't need to, because on a high performance db if I am doing **2 additional queries** for each single query that is a 2 times slower.* Where do you see 2 additional queries? I see an **instead**, which means a query is replaced by another. Nothing added.

Comment: @aruuuuu Ok, please do let me know when you have developed a trigger that (a) doesn't use JOINs, (b) still updates the data correctly, and (c) is more efficient than what I have offered. Don't forget to show your work and explain the differences you observed in Profiler. (P.S. if you care about performance you certainly wouldn't be exposing your servers to Profiler.)

Comment: We're not flamming you. Just explaining that this solution would work and that you have a bad requirement.

Comment: I don't to know how to ask a question again so that I don't get -2. Because I provided a full example and a clear question that is a problem that none of you have actually been able to solve. The fact that you think its not possible does not convince me because you have not proven why it is not possible. Unless whoever gave me minus two explains why I recieved minus two, or the question is answered I am afraid that I will have to escalate this, because some of the comments here are rude and all I was doing was asking a question .

Comment: My first guess is that you have unreasonable requirements. You're basically saying that you want to update one table (MY_TABLE) from another table (inserted), but we're not allowed to use joins in the solution. To me, that's a bad question; it didn't help that you then scolded me for using joins even though I tried to address those concerns. I didn't down-vote, but I can certainly see why someone might.

Comment: Mr. Aaron, I have been able to fill this requirement of no joins on the before insert command, so I should be able to do the same to the update table. Can you please explain mathematically or with an example why not rather then focus and label me as a person that is against joins.

Comment: @aruuuuu it looks like the fact of the matter is that what you're requesting is bad practice and so the community doesn't really see value in encouraging this sort of thing.

Comment: @aruuuuu *shrug* I don't know what else to tell you. This is the solution. I'm looking forward to hearing from you when you have an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger that doesn't use a JOIN but meets the criteria I mentioned above (oh and handles multi-row updates). Your current "no join" requirement sounds a little like "I don't want soup because this one time, at band camp, I ordered soup and there was a fly in it." I'll update the answer with a solution that doesn't use a JOIN, and then you can choose.

Comment: ok . I am still keeping what you said in mind. If I am able to come up with a solution i'll let you know . If not then i'll let you know also.

Comment: @aruuuuu If all updates were 1-row updates, then you wouldn't need a join. But a trigger has to to take care for all cases (1 and multiple row updates) so when an update is done, no error is thrown.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I may not have liked how you tore my question apart, but I do appreciate the answer, and it was helpful in the end. Thankyou :)

Comment: BTW is there no way to have a trigger that fires per row in sql-server?

Comment: @aruuuuu yes, you simulate that by creating a cursor, like the bad example I showed. There is no way to force SQL Server to execute a trigger per row, so you absolutely have to protect yourself from mutli-row operations, always.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want not to see the word `JOIN`, it's possbile, just write it like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [myschema].[my_table_update_ts_trigger] 
ON [myschema].[MY_TABLE]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET FIELD_TO_UPDATE = i.FIELD_TO_UPDATE,
        UPDATE_TS       = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM myschema.MY_TABLE AS t, 
         inserted AS i
    WHERE t.MY_TABLE_ID = i.MY_TABLE_ID;
END
GO
```