# Log Trigger (BEFORE UPDATE) - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table:

`TABLE1`:

```
cod   |           date
 1    |  2008-07-03 00:00:00.000
 2    |  2009-09-03 00:00:00.000
 5    |  2010-12-03 00:00:00.000
```

And I have a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON TABLE1
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE
        @cod   numeric(9)
       ,@date  datetime

    DECLARE c_test cursor for select cod, data from TABLE1

    open c_test 
    fetch next from c_test into @cod, @date

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN

           IF(@date < GETDATE())
           BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TABLE_AUDIT (cod, date, date_alt) VALUES (@cod, @date, GETDATE());
           END
           fetch next from c_test into @cod, @date
        END

    close c_test
    deallocate c_test
```

I want to execute an update like this:

```
update TABLE1 
set date = '2003-07-15 00:00:00.000' 
where cod = 5;
```

and I want the old value from `TABLE1` (before the update, value 2010-12-03 00:00:00.000) inserted into `TABLE_AUDIT` and after `TABLE1` receives the new value 2003-07-15 00:00:00.000 from the above update.

I know SQL Server doesn't have `BEFORE` trigger, so it's because I'm asking any alternatives.

Thanks!

Comment: The `deleted` table in the trigger will contain the old values of the `TABLE1` table.  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/

Comment: The Instead Of trigger replaced the Before trigger, because to make it work just like a Before trigger, all you have to do is put your update in the trigger code at the end.   Simple.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985619/sql-server-before-update-trigger-which-adds-in-a-timestamp-on-a-field-before-upd

Comment: @TabAlleman How will I know inside the trigger the values of the original update?

Comment: Oh gosh - a trigger should be **fast and lean** - please **do NOT** use cursors inside a trigger! This is a sure-fire way to kill all your system performance and scalability! Use a **set-based** approach - and contrary to what you claim, a simple `AFTER INSERT` trigger will do just fine.....

Comment: I removed the cursor and worked like the choose answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this performance killer `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` with cursor,  you can simply have an after trigger something like this ....

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON TABLE1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO TABLE_AUDIT (cod, [date], date_alt)
   SELECT cod, [date], GETDATE()
   FROM deleted 
END
```

Comment: +1 - amen!! This is the way to do it - stay away from cursor in general, and **most definitely** in triggers!

Comment: Worked this way, I removed the cursor. Thanks a lot!